# Xcode 7 UI Testing not recording swipes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a collection view in my app, which is inside a table view cell (yes I know it's weird), and I want to UI Test the scrolling of the collection view. I use the recording button for this, however Xcode identifies the swiping on my collection view as taps. If I manually change the generated UI Test code from `[collectionview tap]` to `[collectionview scrollLeft],` it works, but Xcode won't generate the code for swiping automatically.

What could be the problem?

Comment: In Xcode 7.3.1, I can't get UI Testing to work at all, so just be happy if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah I would be happy, but it does not!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode only recognises a gesture as a swipe if your trajectory with the gesture is fast, straight and true to the (up/down/left/right) direction you are swiping in.

My guess is that this prevents recording drag or tap-and-hold gestures as swipes, since these are unsupported by the recording tool. If you were going for either of those, a tap gesture would be closer.

As a workaround, take note of where you expected a swipe and switch the gesture as you have been doing when your swipes aren't recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should file a bug with Apple and include a sample project.

It may be hard for the recording system to differentiate between a tap, a long press, and a swipe. While I've seen the recording of tap events to be reliable, I find I'm manually typing any steps for swipes or typeText. Generally I use the UI test recording feature to help with identification of particular elements, which I then work with in code to specify the user interactions and asserts.

If you want to create a sample project on github or somewhere with your collectionView-inside-tableViewCell configuration, I'd be willing to take a look.

**EDIT**: After trying your example project, I was sometimes able to get Xcode to record swipeLeft and swipeRight events from the first cell. It's not the most elegant approach, but with the trackpad on my MacBook Air, I start a horizontal swipe with one finger without pressing the mouse button, and then press the button with another finger while the first finger is still swiping.

There were some instances when Xcode recorded this simply as a tap, and at least one instance where it recorded a twoFingerTap.

Comment: That would be great, thanks! The first table cell contains the collection view,  which has two cells (red and blue). https://github.com/balikaa16/Recall-Test